# getch() in TASM

Tags: tasm, getch

So, i'm writing a program in Borland C with TASM in DOS. The program should switch s.c. "tasks" (or processes) until completion, and switching fuction should be operated via key click (getch), and this getch should be written in TASM, inserted in C++ . So, is there any getch() analog in TASM?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what environment that the program is supposed to be running in.

- If it is intended to run in DOS, you can use interrupt `16h` to retrieve pressed keys from the keyboard event handler. I have never used it myself, so I don't know more about it than that.
- You can also install your program as the handler for hardware-interrupts from the keyboard. This is done using subfunction `25h` (specified in AH register) of interrupt `21h`. `AL` specifies the interrupt to install a handler for (keyboard interrupts is `9h`), and `DS:DX` (segment:offset) specifies address to the handler.
- As for Windows I am not as sure, but perhaps this will answer your question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx